# How to view the kernel on MacOS?

Tags: kernel

How to view the kernel on MacOS?

I am learning Linux command line by William Shotts,

The Kernal directory can been accessed by :

```
ls /bin 
# Contain Linux kernal, inital RAM disk image
```

How to view the kernel on MacOS?

```
$ ls /boot
ls: /boot: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Note Linux is not unix and commands will differ from macOS. Use a MacOS based tutorial. – Mark 1 hour ago

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That depends on your version of macOS.

Previously the kernel XNU was locate at the root directory and named mach_kernel:

```
$ ls -la /mach_kernel
```

Apparently starting with 10.11 El Capitan and in mac OS 10.12 Sierra this file was moved and renamed:

```
$ ls -la /System/Library/Kernels/kernel
```

Comment: The second location works for OS10.11  El Capitan.